# jQuery dataTables column sorting issue

Tags: datatables

Using the jQuery dataTables plugin, I have the following rendering a table (code within each render has been simplified for brievity):

```js
table = $('#index')
    .DataTable({
        order: [[1, 'desc']],
        autoWidth: false,
        lengthChange: false,
        pageLength: numRows,
        ajax: {
            url: 'GetTableData/' + application,
            dataSrc: ''
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<span></span>';
                }
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<span></span>';
                }
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<span></span>';
                }
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<span></span>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

No matter what column number or direction I set the `order: [[1,'desc']]` to, it always sorts column 1 asc.

Where am I having a disconnect in my code?

Comment: I may well have had too many shandies this evening but are you just making an ajax call and spitting out empty spans? You can mock ajax calls in JSFiddle, would you like to work one up there so we can see what's gong on?

Comment: Yes. It is impossible to reproduce, please provide an example that actually behave as described.